# $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action on spectra given by inversion

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is a somewhat naive question to which I don't know the answer. There is a map of spectra $S \to S$, defined up to homotopy, given by multiplication by $-1$, and it satisfies the relation $(-1)^2 \simeq 1$. Can this be refined to a strict $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action on the sphere $S$ (and thus on all spectra)?

My feeling is that the answer is probably not, but I haven't been able to prove it. I do know that when one inverts $2$, there is a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action: if I understand correctly, the obstructions to rigidifying a homotopy $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action to an actual $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action on a spectrum $X$ live in the $\mathbb{Z}/2$-cohomology groups of $B Aut(X)$ (where $Aut(X)$ is the monoid of homotopy self-equivalences of $X$), which should be zero when $2$ acts invertibly on $\pi_*X $.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's often no self-map of $S$ which induces multiplication by $(-1)$, because it's usually not cofibrant-fibrant.  There's no *homotopical* obstruction to it existing, because the map $E \mapsto E \wedge S^1$ is an autoequivalence of the stable homotopy category, and $\mathbb{Z}/2$ acts on $S^1$.  Or, if you prefer, we a map of based $\mathbb{Z}/2$-spaces
$$
\mathbb{Z}/2_+ \to S^0
$$
and taking the homotopy fiber of the induced map of suspension spectra, we get a homotopy fiber sequence of spectra with $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action
$$
S \to S \wedge \mathbb{Z}/2_+ \to S
$$
with the first term having a negation action.

One can see visibly that in, e.g., the category of symmetric spectra, the sphere has no $-1$ self-map, but the equivalent free spectrum $F_1(S^1)$ does (for appropriate definitions of "S^1").  In the framework of Adams' "Stable homotopy and generalized homology", because maps are only defined "eventually", the analogue of $F_1(S^1)$ and $S$ are isomorphic objects, so you do have this map.

So if you want it on-the-nose, it depends on your framework.  If you want it homotopically, it always exists (roughly because the map $BGL_1(S) \to B\mathbb{Z}/2$ splits).

Comment: Fair enough. You're absolutely right that there is a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action on the sphere $S^n$ (considered as a topological space), and I'm  embarrassed that I convinced myself that this wasn't true. Thanks!

Comment: @Akhil: I've often managed to convince myself of ridiculous things using fancy language.

Comment: And, to be fair, this is very close to facts which _are_ false.  There is _not_ a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action by $(-1)$ on the sphere which is really "central" in the sense that you can coherently move it across $\wedge$ as you like.

Comment: That's true. Somehow I imagined that having a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action would make the stable category more "additive" than it is (before passage to homotopy), but I never thought about it on spaces. 